# RabbitMQ {handshake_timeout,frame_header}

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I get the following in the rabbitMQ log

> MQ log
>   2018-05-14 10:40:12.841 [info] <0.20724.9> accepting AMQP connection <0.20724.9> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57489 -> //xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672)
>   2018-05-14 10:40:12.856 [info] <0.20724.9> connection <0.20724.9> .xxx.xxx.xxx:57489 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672): user 'Username' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
>   2018-05-14 10:40:12.856 [info] <0.20724.9> closing AMQP connection <0.20724.9> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57489 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'Username')
>   2018-05-14 10:40:14.728 [info] <0.20741.9> accepting AMQP connection <0.20741.9> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57491 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672)
>   2018-05-14 10:40:14.728 [info] <0.20741.9> connection <0.20741.9> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57491 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672): user 'Username' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
>   2018-05-14 10:40:14.744 [info] <0.20741.9> closing AMQP connection <0.20741.9> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57491 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'Username')
>   2018-05-14 10:40:14.884 [info] <0.20756.9> accepting AMQP connection <0.20756.9> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57493 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672)
>   2018-05-14 10:40:14.884 [info] <0.20756.9> connection <0.20756.9> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57493 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672): user 'Username' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
>   2018-05-14 10:40:14.900 [info] <0.20756.9> closing AMQP connection <0.20756.9> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57493 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'Username')
>   2018-05-14 10:40:16.756 [info] <0.20771.9> accepting AMQP connection <0.20771.9> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57495 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672)
>   2018-05-14 10:40:16.928 [info] <0.20774.9> accepting AMQP connection <0.20774.9> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57496 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672)
>   2018-05-14 10:40:36.350 [warning] <0.20771.9> closing AMQP connection <0.20771.9> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57495 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672):
>   {handshake_timeout,frame_header}
>   2018-05-14 10:40:36.350 [warning] <0.20774.9> closing AMQP connection <0.20774.9> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57496 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672):
>   {handshake_timeout,frame_header}

I have the following in my config

```
[
{handshake_timeout, 0},
].
```

as well as an environment variable heartbeat with a value of 0
my code is as follows

```
public static void Recieve()
{
    var User = figurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQUserName"];
    var Pass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQPass"];
    var Server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"];
    var Port = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

    factory.UserName = User;
    factory.Password = Pass;
    factory.VirtualHost = "/";
    factory.HostName = Server;
    factory.Port = Port;

    IConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();

    IModel channel = conn.CreateModel();
    channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "QueName",
                         durable: true,
                         exclusive: false,
                         autoDelete: false,
                         arguments: null);
    //channel.ExchangeDeclare("amq.direct", ExchangeType.Direct);
    channel.QueueBind("QueName", "amq.direct", "", null);
    bool sent = true;
    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
    consumer.Received += (ch, ea) =>
    {
        var body = ea.Body;
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

        sent = Send(message);

        if (sent)
        {
            channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, true);
        }
        else
        {
            channel.BasicReject(ea.DeliveryTag, true);
        }

    };
    String consumerTag = channel.BasicConsume("QueName", false`enter code here`, consumer);
};
```

Comment: but what is your question ?

Comment: and can you format your log more properly with some carriage returns so other users can help you more easely.

Answer (score 2):

If you set `handshake_timeout` to `0`, AMQP handshake can never succeed since it will immediately timeout. This is what you are seeing in the log.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your rabbit node name is error,you can enable rabbitmq-plugins rabbitmq_management,then visit web to modify clouster name the same as your rabbitmq-env.conf NODENAME.